# Pinning python application running through Python interpreter

Tags: python, windows, taskbar

I have an application I run using `pythonw.exe`. I just click on my `.pyw` file and it runs. It's using Qt and I have set up an icon that both shows in the window and in the taskbar.

However when I try to pin it, it pins the python IDLE incorrectly instead of the application itself. It makes some sense since it is a python file run from `pythonw.exe`. Example below:

[image: Taskbar issue]

So how do I proceed to run the application the right way so I can pin it to the taskbar?

Comment: You should be able to pin a shortcut. It may need a fully-qualified command line, e.g. `"path\to\pythonw.exe" "path\to\script.pyw"`. Otherwise you could use PyInstaller to freeze your script as an executable.

Comment: Thanks. I had traid shortcut with no avail but seems that putting pythonw.exe before the target fixes the issue!

Answer (score 1):

As eryksun said you need a shortcut with `pythonw.exe "Path to pyw file"` in target.